# How to break number down into its digits without converting input to strings?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, sorting, modulo

I'm trying to create a program which has the user input an integer and then the program adds 8 to each place (modulo 10).

An input of **4444** results in **2222**, and **1111** results in **9999**.

Since I don't want to convert the input to string before looping through each place (thousands, tens, ones, etc), I don't know if this involves looping through a one dimensional array or not. How would I do this in java or in pseudo code?

Comment: Why don't you try something, and then come back to StackOverflow if you have problems?

Answer (score 1):

```
// length = the length of the number, you can get it by log function
int ans = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    new_digit = ((number / Math.pow(10, i)) % 10 + 8) % 10;
    ans += new_digit * Math.pow(10, i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take remainder with 10 to get the unit place digit, to remove the unit place digit divide by 10.

ex.

```
1234 % 10 = 4   <--first digit
1234 / 10 = 123  <-- next number

123 % 10 = 3    <--second digit
123 / 10 = 12   <-- next number
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to spoil you with the solution, but I can give you one tip:
As you already know you get the most right digitby doing `Number % 10`, e.g. `9999 % 10 = 9`, right?
And also dividing by 10 "cuts" the most right digit, e.g. `9999 / 10 = 999`.
This implicates, that you should have worked through all digits if your last division equals 0. Doing this you can work on all digits seperately. The hard part no is putting those single digits together, and that is achievable if you "remember" their decimal powers. This would at least be one way to do it fully numerical without using strings or anything.

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be done playing with combination of modulo and divisions, no need for arrays...

in the example I define the number to add (in your case 8) as "additivity" (feel free to rename it)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int additivity = 8;
    int k = 4321;
    int result = 0;
    System.out.println("The Original number:\n" + k);
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        result = (k % (int) Math.pow(10, 5 - i)) / (int) Math.pow(10, (4 - i));
        System.out.print((result + additivity) >= 10 ? (result + additivity) % 10 : (result + additivity));
    }
}
```